# Dirac delta function divided by Dirac delta function

Tags: distribution-theory, dirac-delta

Is the following defined: (Dirac delta function divided by Dirac delta function)

$$f = \frac{\delta}{\delta} = ?$$

Comment: I have purged all the comments from this post. Please remember to keep comments *on topic*, and try not to berate other users.

Comment: @Flybynight Please join me in chat so that we may discuss this further.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't know if the following is what you are looking for, but: To give the division a sense, what you can do is look for functions $\phi \in \mathcal E^0(\mathbb R)$ (that is continuous functions $\mathbb R \to \mathbb R$  that fulfill $\phi \delta = \delta$. As for any $\psi \in \mathcal D(\mathbb R)$ we have $$(\phi \delta)(\psi) =\delta(\phi\psi) = \phi(0)\psi(0) = \phi(0)\delta(\psi), $$
that is $\phi \delta = \phi(0)\delta$, so we have $$\phi \delta = \delta \iff  \phi(0) = 1. $$

Comment: what is \D(\R)?

Comment: It is the usual notation for $C^\infty_c$ with the good topology used in Distribution theory.

Answer (score 1):

Remember $\delta$ is 'operationally' defined by its effect under integration. So $\delta$/$\delta$ needs more context, for example, like

($\delta$(x-y),f(x))/($\delta$(x-y),g(x)),

where (.,.) is the inner product, before the question can be answered. In this case  $\delta$/$\delta$ = 1 only if f(y)=g(y). Otherwise the results could be one of many other things.